# c# S3 PutObject is too slow

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I read some articles that tells that `PutObject` method of `Amazon S3` API is very slow but non of them gave a real answer of how to deal with it.

When I upload a picture of size 500 kb it takes me about 2-3 seconds which seems to me very much.

Could you please advice me what can I do to improve the performance of the uploads?

```
var appConfig = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
var s3Client = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(appConfig["AWSAccessKey"], appConfig["AWSSecretKey"],RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(appConfig["AWSRegion"]));

var request = new PutObjectRequest
{
    BucketName = bucketName,
    Key = path,
    InputStream = filestream,
    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
};

_AmazonS3Client.PutObject(request); //Takes 2-3 seconds for 500 kb pictures
```

I also read someone said that this should help `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;` but this code didn't help me.

Comment: It more looks like an network related issue, either on your end or on Amazon's end. Do a network trace to get more details on what is happening. You could also spin-up a virtual machine in the same datacentre/region where S3 is and then run the code and your measurements there to rule out network/ISP issues.

Comment: @rene My network is very good and it is slow for some weeks...

Comment: When I do a tracert for an S3 endpoint in central europe I get 13 hops and 22 ms as response. How is yours?

Comment: @rene I am not familiar with tracert. I wrote in cmd "tracert MyServerIP" and started to receive results - it writes over a maximum of 30 hops and then started writing ms which at first were less then 20 but then timeouts started, I am not sure what does it means.

Comment: If you dig into network performance you better make sure you understand those tools. You should do a `tracert` to whatever comes out of this: `RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(appConfig["AWSRegion"])` or lookup your region endpoint [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region). If it starts to timeout that is OK-ish. means not all routers allow ICMP traffic. The result tells you two things: How many network components there are between you and the public S3 endpoint. Lower numbers are better. The milliseconds is a rough indication for the network speed.

Comment: Just to rule out a local disk issue, can you copy the filestream in a memorystream first and then assign the memorystream to `InputStream`?

Comment: The sensible approach to investigate this is to disable https and use a packet sniffer like `tshark` to observe what's actually happening.  Short of that, you're guessing... but S3 uploads are not slow by any reasonable definition of the term.